# How does the behavior of `in` differ from `index` in python lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, containment

Much to my own frustration, I managed to make a list of objects in python such that the following fails:

```
if foo in lst:
    lst.index(foo) # ValueError: <foo> is not in list
```

I assure you, no trickery here:

1. `foo` is an object with a custom `__hash__` and `__eq__`, and is not being modified elsewhere
2. both functions are idempotent and do not modify state
3. `lst` is a standard python `[]` with no curses

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: Can you show us the custom `__eq__` method?

Comment: Can you show us the actual error, with traceback? "I get an error" is the worst bug report possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Making a minimal demonstration now

Comment: @00500005: I didn't downvote, btw, but without a traceback and `__eq__` method we'll have to speculate more than necessary.

Comment: For the record `__hash__` isn't at play here; that's for dictionary keys and `set` values, not lists.

Comment: I was unable to simplify it much. I might come back to this once I actually fix the bug. For the curious: http://pastebin.com/fWF9mdbQ

Comment: @00500005: `all([s in other for s in self]+[self.name == other.name])` can better be expressed as `all(s in other for s in self) and self.name == other.name`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Also the bug was in `Grammar.__eq__`. I didn't check if `other` had values not in `self`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between `obj in listobject` (or `listobject.__contains__(obj)`) and `listobject.index()` is that comparison is *inverted*.

`list_contains` does:

```
for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
    cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                       Py_EQ);
```

while `listindex` does;

```
for (i = start; i < stop && i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
    int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(self->ob_item[i], v, Py_EQ);
```

where `el` and `v` are the looked-for object, and `PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i)` and `self->ob_item[i]` are the objects contained in the list.

So `lst.index()` throws a `ValueError` exception because all of the `other.__eq__(foo)` calls return `False` and `foo.__eq__(other)` is never consulted. `foo in lst` works because `foo.__eq__(other)` does return `True` for at least one value.

You haven't given us a sample list and `__eq__` implementation to verify *why* `__eq__` returns `False` for all `other.__eq__(foo)` calls.

Comment: ...or maybe you just had to speculate the exact right amount, as usual :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a ton. Deep object stacks make it difficult to make a minimal reproduction.

Comment: My Issue: `[f for f in lst if f == foo] != [f for f in lst if foo == f]`

Comment: @00500005: clearly, your `f.__eq__` methods need working on. Return the `NotImplemented` singleton when you cannot determine that two objects are not equal, *not* `False`, and the inverse will be tested too.